# ¿Cómo acceder a una función en una clase C# desde JavaScript Usando AJAX?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, webforms

Tengo una aplicación web con C# en la cual intento acceder a una función desde javascript usando ajax.
No tengo problemas si la funcion la ubico en el codebehind que esta enlazado al webform:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static object getJsonDataProducts()
    {
        object products;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            //Obtener utl de la aplicacion web
            string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            //Obtener los datos del json en formato texto
            String json = webClient.DownloadString(url + @"\App_Data\sample.json");

            //convertir json en series de objetos
            JsonDataModel.ProductsOrders data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDataModel.ProductsOrders>(json);

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            products = ser.Serialize(data.products);
        }

        return products;
    }
```

En este caso, hago el llamado a la funcion desde el javascript y accede sin ningun problema.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getJsonDataProducts",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
            ...
        });
    });

</script>
```

Ahora, el problema es el siguiente, quiero sacar esa funcion del archivo Default.aspx.cs y colocarlo en una clase aparte (ClaseAparte.cs) pero no sé como podría acceder a esa funcion desde el ajax intente simplemente creando la clase y reemplazar la url en el llamado al ajax pero no funcionó.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ClaseAparte.cs/getJsonDataProducts",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
            ...
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Ese archivo `ClaseAparte.cs` debería ser un `.ashx` o un `.aspx`

Comment: @fredyfx solo pueden hacerse llamados desde ajax a controles o a webforms? no es posible acceder a un metodo o una funcion en una clase independiente?

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que estoy viendo, funcionaría con controles ajax, webforms, mvc, webApi. Para que puedas hacer llamadas a métodos de la manera en que lo estás buscando, necesitas SignalR + WebApi o MVC.

Comment: Para que tengas una idea, aquí tienes algo similar a lo que estás usando: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function